# How can I make VS Code editor tabs close button go on left side?

Tags: tabs, customization, visual-studio-code

How do I move the 'x' button to close an editor tab to the left side of the tab?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

After searching endlessly for a solution to this, I found one, and decided it might be appreciated by others to know how to get their tab 'x' button on the left side.

Simply add the following to your USER SETTINGS json file.

```
"workbench.editor.tabCloseButton": "left",
```

Mac users rejoice!

Comment: I was in pain, and I didn't know it. Thanks.

Comment: Life saver! This comes with the added benefit of being able to close multiple tabs faster when they have different widths.

Comment: this setting will be gone in VS Code 1.85. see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77414834/11107541) for more up to date info.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [reka18's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50176249/how-can-i-make-vs-code-editor-tabs-close-on-left-side/50176392#50176392):

Click on `Preferences` > `Settings` and type `workbench editor tab`

Observe the option `Tab Close Button`, there is a drop down, click and select `left`.

[image: vs-code-tab-configuration]

Answer (score 2):

If you are here in 2023, there is a better option (not sure if that was the case earlier) -

1. `Cmd + Shift + P` => Opens a search bar with a command `>`
   [image]
2. Type in `Open Settings` and select `Preferences: Open Settings (UI)`
3. You will get an interface where you again get a search bar on top -
4. Type in `Close button` and you will see the following -
   [image]
5. Update how you want it and that's it! Not even saving is required

Answer (score 1):

(in [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson))

#### For VS Code 1.85+

```json
"workbench.editor.tabActionLocation": "left",
```

Setting description:

> Controls the position of the editor's tabs action buttons (close, unpin). This value is ignored when `#workbench.editor.showTabs#` is not set to `multiple`

For the change history, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/196972.

#### For VS Code pre-1.85

```json
"workbench.editor.tabCloseButton": "left",
```

Setting description:

> Controls the position of the editor's tabs close buttons, or disables them when set to 'off'. This value is ignored when `workbench.editor.showTabs` is not set to `multiple`.