# Is there a way to make all editor tabs in VS Code's workbench the same width?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I added `"workbench.editor.tabSizing": "shrink"` to my settings, and while that makes all the tabs fit in on the bar, it doesn't make them equal width. I want them to be equal width so I can quickly close out of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer for VS Code's May 2023 release

There's a new value for the `workbench.editor.tabSizing` option: `"fixed"`. You can find the PR that implemented it here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/181729.

#### Answer for pre-May 2023 release of VS Code

> Is there a way to make all tabs the same width?

Apparently not.

As you can already see, at the time of this writing, there are only two options for `workbench.editor.tabSizing`, and neither do what you are looking for.

And googling "`github vscode issues tab sizing uniform width`", I came across three issue tickets asking for this at various points in time that all got closed:

- [Tab sizes should be a fixed size #38594](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/38594) closed as a duplicate [Allow to close multiple tabs without moving the mouse after closing one #40290](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/40290). I suppose it's closed as an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)? Lucky for you, it's the exact same XY problem you have. So subscribe to that issue ticket. <sup><sub>[You can show your support for the issue ticket by giving a thumbs up reaction to the issue. But please *don't* make a "me too" comment.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup>
- [Uniform tab size for opened editors #146689](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146689) closed as a duplicate, but either I'm blind, or they forgot to comment what the duplicate target is.
- [Tab wrap - add a setting for uniform tab sizing across all rows #115132](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/115132) closed as "out-of-scope". [Quote](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/115132#issuecomment-934304074):

  > We closed this issue because we don't plan to address it in the foreseeable future. You can find more detailed information about our decision-making process [here](https://aka.ms/vscode-out-of-scope). If you disagree and feel that this issue is crucial: We are happy to listen and to reconsider.

---

In terms of the XY problem here,

- It's also worth noting- if you use the mouse middle click (or equivalent action with a touchpad) to close tabs, then it's much less a problem of hitting the close button, since with that approach, the entire tab handle is one big close button.
- And you can just as well make the tab close button go on the left of the tab handle by following [How can I make VS Code editor tabs close button go on left side?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50176249/11107541).

Comment: Actually, this is the best of both worlds! I can have tabs as long as the file names but shrink them if the tabs overflow the bar, and be able to close multiple tabs quickly, thanks!